# How to create a Magento 1.6 shipping module?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create my own Magento shipping module in Magento 1.6. Since I have no experience making Magento modules, I'm trying to find a blank custom shipping module to add stuff to. There are a few tutorials online, but they all seem outdated or loaded with bugs.

Can anyone point me to something like [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module) but working for 1.6? 
Or perhaps a blank module already packaged in a zip file?

Comment: Did you get the empty module, or made your own module? I am also looking for a sample module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a package for shipping module than you should follow this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ig-multi-flat-shipping.html
(or any other free shipping extension)

After installing this extension you can go through its Code that will enable you to create your own shipping module.

THANKS